# Choosing polar aprotic solvents for substitution reaction

Tags: organic-chemistry

1. It is known that common polar aprotic solvents include acetone and DMSO. Since they do not have hydrogen bonded to highly electronegative atom, they cannot only form dipole-dipole interaction with nucleophile, instead of hydrogen bond & ion-dipole interaction.
2. Moreover, the electrons in 2 R-CH3 groups in acetone / DMSO are repelled by electrons of the nucleophile, hence increasing the distance of dipole-dipole interactions, further decreasing the solvating effect.

My question is: from (2), is it better to use reagents that have more bulky R groups linking to the partial positive atom like pentan-3-one & diethylsulphoxide instead? I know this will decrease the polarity of solvent, but won't these better decrease the dipole-dipole interaction hence further increasing the nucleophilicity?

Comment: Your alternatives are not available in bulk as solvents. The differences in properties from those readily available are minor and do not justify sourcing them.

Comment: @Waylander Thanks! So the dominant effect is just about the inability of forming strong ion-dipole interactions to the nucleophile but not so related to electron repulsions, hence those are not common as solvents?

Comment: Any part of a reaction that can be done by a wide variety of compounds would be done in the cheapest way possible at the same time minimizing the byproducts formed due to using a given compound. So, it's more about the economic benefit here is what I gather from @Waylander's answer